# Generate Binary string based on Dictionary values in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary like `dict = { A:3, B:5, C:3, D:2, E:6, F:5}`

I would like to write a function that generates a concatenated binary stream based on the value as binary bit width.

If width is 7 : binary 0101010 - 7 bits starting with 0 on lsb position

Suppose if function is `func(B, D, E)` : my output should generate a concatenated binary stream of

```
0101010101010
```

because:

```
{01010 (B) + 10 (D) +  101010 (E)}
```

The lsb bit of each value have to be always zero.

Expected output `0101010101010`.

Here is what I tried:

```
def Generate_binary_stream(width):
output_stream = ""
bit = 0
for i in range (0,width):
    output_stream += str(bit)
    bit = ~bit

print ("The bitstream for width %d is %s"%(width,output_stream))
```

Output that I'm getting : `0-10-10-10-10` (how to eliminate hyphens?)

Comment: how is `01010 ` the binary representation of `B`?

Comment: Since B's width is 5, starting with 0 on LSB, its value will be alternate 0's and 1's upto five digits -01010

Comment: Hint: write a function `get_binary_stream(size)` that returns a single string of the desired size. Then use that to get your concatenated binary steam.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert to binary with `bin` function :

```
  my_list=[]
  >>> def conv(*args):
    ...  for i in args:
    ...    my_list.append(bin(dict[i]))
         print ''.join(map(str,my_list))

  >>> conv('A','B','C')
  0b110b1010b110b110b1010b11
```

Comment: I don't want the binary equivalent value of the key. Its just alternate 0s and 1's upto width

Comment: how does your output match the expected?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham ... with the OP's help i will change it !

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly, but this seems to produce the desired result:

```
width = { 'A':3, 'B':5, 'C':3, 'D':2, 'E':6, 'F':5}

def bits(width):
    return ('0' if width % 2 else '') + '10' * (width // 2)

def to_bits(s):
    return ''.join(bits(width[x]) for x in s)

print to_bits('BDE') # 0101010101010
```